# What is the Baire characteristic of the real number line?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, cardinals, baire-category

For any cardinal $\alpha$ we define the space $X$ to be $\alpha$-Baire to mean every union of less than $\alpha$-many nowhere dense sets is a proper subset of $X$. The Baire category theorem states that every Banach space / topological group is $\aleph_1$-Baire.

Define the *Baire Characteristic* $b(X)$ to be the least cardinal $\beta$ such that $X$ fails to be $\beta$-Baire.

Obviously the Baire category theorem implies $b(\mathbb R) \ge \aleph_0$. But can anything further be said? For example is it true that $b(\mathbb R) =\mathfrak c $? Note this is the highest possible value since $\mathfrak c = |\mathbb R|$.

We always have $b(\mathbb R) = b([0,1]) $ since each contains a nice subset homeomorphic to the other. What is known more generally about the range of allowed values for $b(X)$ when $X$ is a compact metric space? For example is it possible to construct such spaces with *arbitrarily large* Baire characteristic? We can make this precise. . . .

> **Conjecture**: For every cardinal $\alpha < \mathfrak c$ there exists a compact metric space $X$ with $b(X) \ge \alpha$.

Is this true?

Comment: Read about cardinal characteristics of the continuum. Specifically, the covering number of the meager ideal.

Comment: The Baire characteristic is the same for all complete separable metric spaces. It can be $\mathfrak{c}> \aleph_1$ in some models of set theory (Martin's axiom). Follow @AsafKaragila's advice.

Comment: Note that the Baire category theorem actually gives that $b(\mathbb R) \geq \aleph_1$ (not $\aleph_0$ -- $\geq \aleph_0$ would merely say that $\mathbb R$ is not a union of finitely many nowhere dense sets).